Why won't PostgreSQL import my csv dates, despite being in YYYY-MM-DD format?
I have recently started playing with PostgreSQL 17. I'm trying to import a csv file with some fairly simple information, but it keeps failing:

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: "dateofpost"
CONTEXT: COPY posts, line 1, column dateofpost: "dateofpost"


dateofpost is date format - which should be YYYY-MM-DD with no timestamp, from what I can tell.
At first I thought it was because the date format was DD/MM/YYYY, but even after changing it to YYYY-MM-DD I get the same error.
I am using the pgAdmin 4 import/export feature. If I remove the date column everything imports fine.

Please review [mre]. Without the table DDL, example input file, and command details (either the actual command or selected options for GUI interactions), any suggestions from the SO community are just guesses. Frank's assessment of the problem is likely correct; however, the same exception could also be reported if the problem were caused by mismatched column order.

You didn’t share the entire command, but most likely you forgot to tell the database that the first line contains the header. “dateofpost” is definitely not a valid date

Move the Header switch to the Yes position to include the table header with the data rows. If you include the table header, the first row of the file will contain the column names.



@Zegarek: Thanks! I don't have access to pgAdmin myself
